# How to filter by date in realm javaScript

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

please check my little part of code & database schema.

my schema

```
export const DailyPerformanceMeterDataSchema = {
    name: DAILY_PERFORMANCE_METER_DATA_SCHEMA,
    primaryKey : 'id',
    properties: {
        id: 'int',
        createdDateTime : 'date',
        maxTarget : 'int',
        totalRead : 'int'
    }
}


Realm.open(databaseOptions).then(realm => {
    let filteredPerformanceLists = realm.objects(DAILY_PERFORMANCE_METER_DATA_SCHEMA).filtered(`createdDateTime == ${new Date()}`);
    console.log(filteredPerformanceLists);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

i tried this but it showing me error like..

> Error: createdDateTime == Thu Mar 29 2018 19:22:32 GMT+0530 (IST):1:23(23): Invalid predicate.]

for your kind of information,
I'm using,

```
"react": "16.2.0",
"react-native": "0.53.0",
"realm": "^2.2.15"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`let filteredPerformanceLists = realm.objects(DAILY_PERFORMANCE_METER_DATA_SCHEMA).filtered('createdDateTime == $0', new Date());`